# Collection View horizontal direction with dynamic height

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uiscrollview

I have a collection view with direction set to horizontal and paging enable. The things is, the height of my collection cell each page sometimes is higher than the phone screen size. What I want to achieve is user can scroll down the cell and swipe right to the next page.

Currently, I only able to display the collection cell one full page, without manage to scroll downward based on content height. Here some code:

```
extension EventListDetailsVC: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return dataArray.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cat = dataArray[indexPath.row]

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "celldetails", for: indexPath) as? EventListDetailsCVC
        cell?.imageEvent.image = UIImage(named: cat.imageEvent)
        cell?.eventTitleLabel.text = cat.titleEvent
        cell?.eventDescriptionLabel.text = cat.content

        return cell!
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {


        return CGSize(width: self.collectionView.frame.size.width, height: self.collectionView.frame.size.height)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
        return UIEdgeInsets.zero
     }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 0
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 0
    }
}
```

---

this how it should be

### [image: this how it should be]

I tried to embed my collectionView into tableView, but it seems does not work because I have dynamic height in a cell.

Is it another way to achive this?

p/s I just started learning swift, thanks.

Comment: Try using Table view in cell of collection view, you can add your collection view cell as it is in Table view header, don't implement the table cells and all that

Comment: @HussainChhatriwala make sense, will try later.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried embedding a scroll view inside each collection view cell?

That would make sure that the collection view cell height never exceeds the phone height while the scroll view will work on displaying more content as you scroll down whether it be text or images or whatever view you decide to embed in the scroll view itself.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try [UIPageViewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipageviewcontroller) with the `scroll` transition style. It has native pagination between pages.

Every page should have UIScrollView.